# PHP error in insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm going crazy, where is the error in this snippet?

```php
<?php
include('db.php');
switch ($_REQUEST['tab']) {
  case 'categorie':
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorie");
    echo "INSERT INTO categorie ( id, nome, free, pos ) VALUES " ;
    $a=0;
    while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
      if($a!=0)
        echo ",";
      echo "(".$tmp['id'].", '".$tmp['nome']."', ".$tmp['free'].", ".$tmp['pos'].")";
      $a=1;
    }
    break;
  case 'articoli':
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articoli");
    echo "INSERT INTO articoli ( id, titolo, testo, sottocategoria, free, pos ) VALUES " ;
    $a=0;
    while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
      if($a!=0)
        echo ",";
      echo "(".$tmp['id'].", '".$tmp['titolo']."', '".$tmp['testo']."', ".$tmp['sottocategoria'].", ".$tmp['free'].", ".$tmp['pos'].")";
      $a=1;
    }     
    break;
  case 'sottocategorie':
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sottocategorie");
    echo "INSERT INTO sottocategorie ( id, nome, categoria, free, pos ) VALUES " ;
    $a=0;
    while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
      if($a!=0)
        echo ",";
      echo "(".$tmp['id'].", '".$tmp['nome']."', ".$tmp['categoria'].", ".$tmp['free'].", ".$tmp['pos'].")";
      $a=1;
    }
    break;
}
?>
```

says there is a syntax error near the,

I post the entire code...............................................................................

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do do you want to select the data from one table and insert them into another table? then use `INSERT INTO SELECT`: `INSERT INTO table(...) SELECT ... FROM table`

Comment: `table` is a MySQL keyword.

Comment: Four columns in a table, all called `x`.... is your database structure really so secret that you can't show the real queries and code?

Comment: print and provide us full query which generates

Comment: I do not think need to know the names of the fields

Comment: INSERT INTO campo ( id, name, gris, res ) VALUES (141, 'example', 0, 0)

Comment: You ask "where is the error in this snippet?" Same question here, in which line does the error occur? Or is the error in the SQL statement you build?

Comment: I don't know... The error is Failure 1 (near ",": syntax error) on 0x338898 when preparing ' THE ABOVE QUERY '

Comment: This looks more like a trolling attempt than a real question. If you want to be serious, use a decent IDE and give us some real code. Unless you want speculative answers.

Comment: @Gianni - `I do not think need to know the names of the fields`... knowing the real table and field names would allow us to eliminate the possibility that one of them was a MySQL reserved word - regardless of what you think, IT DOES MAKE A DIFFERENCE

Comment: Please update your question to give the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After your clarification below, the problem is not in your PHP, it's in executing the *output* of the PHP script.

Your PHP will generate output similar to;

```
INSERT INTO A (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)   // <-- note the missing semicolon
INSERT INTO B (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)   // <-- note the missing semicolon
```

Add those missing semicolons, and you should be up and working.

---- Original answer ----

```
while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
{
   ...
}
break;
```

You have a `break` outside your loop, which is (unless this is nested inside another loop) is a syntax error.

Also, your SQL selects from a table named `table`, which is a reserved MySQL keyword. If you *really* have a table called `table`, you'll need to change the query to;

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
```

Comment: No, table is a name that I put it to hide the real name. The break I put it there because the snippet I posted is inside a switch case. Hel me please :'(

Comment: @Giannirossi I can't help you more than that unless you post more context and code that is not intentionally broken to begin with. The limited code you posted runs with the two above changes, there's nothing left to correct.

Comment: I posted all the code .. excuse

Comment: @Giannirossi Could you add the exact error message to your question? Does it _really_ say `THE ABOVE QUERY` or is that just an abbreviation?

Comment: Sorry sorry, here is the error Failure 1 (near ",": syntax error) on 0x338508 when preparing '     
INSERT INTO categorie ( id, nome, free, pos ) VALUES (141, 'Piante', 0, 0)